# Chai Array to contain any member?

Tags: javascript, arrays, chai

I'm currently querying a database documents that contain the category: foo or bar. However I am finding it quite difficult to test this.

Here is a sample of the array that I want to test:

```
 var array = [
    {category: ['foo'] }, 
    {category: ['foo', 'bar'] }, 
    {category: ['foo'] }
];

expect(array[0].category).to.include.any.members(['foo', 'bar']);
```

However it doesn't seem to work properly, it looks for each member to be present.
I would like the test to be able to check each element of the array to include foo OR bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no `or` method or something like this in Chai.

So I think you must loop through your array like this:

```
var array = [
    {category: ['foo'] }, 
    {category: ['foo', 'bar'] }, 
    {category: ['foo'] }
];

array.forEach(function(item) {
    expect(item).to.have.any.keys('category');

    item.category.forEach(function(catItem) {
        expect(catItem).to.match(/foo|bar/);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok great! I thought I might need to resort to regular expressions in the end.